# How to realize pagination by dragging the scroll bar to the top or bottom position?

Tags: angular, typescript, pagination, angular-directive

Recently, I want to realize my pagination function for a list of items. Now the pagination works fine with scrolling event and it turns to the next-page when I scroll to the bottom or to the previous-page when I scroll to the top of the list area. But when I drag the scroll bar to the bottom, the arrow button of the scroll bar turns to be greY and I cannot load data any more.
I just want to know which event I should use in @HostListener or there maybe other ways to realize this functionality?

Each time, 25 items will be loaded when I scroll to the bottom and I keep 50 items in total in the DOM tree. So there are no more than 50 items in the DOM tree all the time.

The reason I did not use virtual scroll is that items in the list do not have the same height so I cannot apply a fixed-height property for virtual scroll.

```js
//scroll-directive
@HostListener('mousewheel', ['$event'])  //mousewheel
  track(event: WheelEvent) {
    this.scrolls.next(event);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to listen on `scroll` event instead of `mousewheel`. Scroll event is also fired if you drag the scrollbar. If you want to implement a more performant version which does not run ChangeDetection on every scroll event, you can do it like this:

```
@ViewChild('scrollContainer') private scrollContainer: ElementRef;

ngOnInit() {
    this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
        this.scrollContainer.nativeElement.addEventListener('scroll', (ev: Event) => {
            // Do your fetch checks here and don't forget 
            // to run the fetching inside the zone again
            this.ngZone.run(() => {
                // Do fetch
            });
        });
    });
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you can listen to `mousewheel` but the handler is not fired when listening on `scroll` then maybee not your host element is the scrolling container, but a child of it. Then `mousewheel` is still triggered on the host element, because it is bubbeling, but `scroll` doesnt.

Comment: I have tried to listen to scroll event and I changed my code into this  @HostListener('scroll', ['$event']) track(event: Scroll) but now nothing happens.

Comment: Hmm maybee you can create https://stackblitz.com/ to reproduce the issue. Or try my solution.

Comment: Thanks any way. I still cannot scroll. I need to use the event property to know it is scrolling down or scrolling up. Like in the wheelEvent I can use the event.deltaY property.

Comment: @AmyChang If you want to implement bidirectional-infinite-scroll you can also take a look at this lib https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-scroll